# DialogFragment получение объекта из адаптера выполнение метода в адаптере

Tags: java, android

Имеется Recycler.Adapter. в нем по нажатию на элемент открывает DialogFragment, в котором нужно нажать метод удаления и вернуть ответ adapterу

Как передать объект в DialogFragment и получить ответ от DialogFragment в Adapter?

Adapter

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView textViewProductName;
        public TextView textViewProductColor;
        public TextView textViewProductCategory;


        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewProductName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewProductName);
            textViewProductColor = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewProductColor);
            textViewProductCategory = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewProductCategory);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    DialogBasketItem dialogBasketItem = new DialogBasketItem();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity)itemView.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager();

                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    dialogBasketItem.show(fragmentTransaction,"dialog");


                }
            });

        }
    }
```

DialogFragment

```
public class DialogBasketItem extends DialogFragment {

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setTitle("Выберите действие");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Удалить", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //Действие
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Отмена", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Comment: вам точно в адаптер надо данные передавать? а то обычно удаление происходит в активности с `RecyclerView` и `getAdapter().notifyDataSetChaged()`

Comment: а так, вообще, через интерфэйс в активности вызывается паблик метод адаптера

Comment: Мне нужно в DialogFragment Object передать и оттуда выполнить метод ObjectBasket.deleteObject(), после этого обновить adapter, чтобы в RecyclerView обновились данные

Comment: сложнааа... передавайте id, находите из "лабе" по id, отображайте, удаляйте, вызывайте метод в активности `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: @Jarvis_J вообще для удаления есть более уместный  метод notifyItemRemoved()

Comment: Но это мы удаляем только из recyclerview, а мне еще нужно удалить из лабе. Только я не пойму как по id object получить

Comment: удаляйте из `ArrayList`, если вы правильно его задали (через =), удалится и из "лабы". id - обычно индекс в массиве.